# How to pass a pointer to method as a parameter?

Tags: c++

I want to pass a method as an argument to a method which takes an int and returns void:

```
void A::SetCallback(void (*callback)(int))
{
   .....................
}

void B::test()
{
   a->SetCallback(&B::Done); //
}

void B::Done(int i)
{
   ..........................
}
```

Inside `test()` I get this error:

```
Error   1   error C2664: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__thiscall B::* )(int)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(int)'
```

I saw some example on StackOverflow how to fix this but it uses elements from C++11, to which I do not have access.
How can I fix this using C++03 ?

Comment: your `SetCallback` takes a pointer to a free function. Pointers to class methods are different, because they implicitly take a pointer to the object as parameter.

Comment: How would you call `B::Done` in `A` if you were able to take it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot pass a non-static method to a function that takes a pointer to a function. Functions and methods are two completely different things. In order to invoke a non-static method you have to, obviously, have an object whose method you're invoking.

If, in your example, `Done()` is a static class method, then, yes, you can pass it this way, since a static class method is just another name for a function.

It is possible to have a pointer to a class method:

```
void A::SetCallback(void (B::*callback)(int))
{

}

void B::test()
{
   a->SetCallback(&B::Done); //
}

void B::Done(int i)
{
   ..........................
}
```

But in order to invoke the class method, you need an object whose method to invoke:

```
B *object=give_me_a_pointer_to_b_from_somewhere();

(object->*callback)(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

`&ClassName::method_name` creates the pointer and `void(ClassName::*)(int, char*)` is the type.

```
void go(void(ClassName::*parameter_name)(int, char*));

go(&ClassName::method_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a pointer to class method (which is of type `void (B::*) (int)` in your case) to a pointer to a free function.

What would happen if you could?

```
void f (void (*g) (int)) {
    g(2);
}

struct A {
    int x;
    void foo (int c) { x += c; }
};

f(&A::foo); // Oh oh! Where will I find `x` in the call `g(2)`?
```

If you only want pointer to method of `B`, you need to change the callback type:

```
void A::SetCallback(void (B::*callback)(int)) { }
```

But then you need an instance of `B` to call your callback, e.g.:

```
B b;
(b.*callback)(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using following code. It is not pretty, but you asking for C++03:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

class AbstractCallback {
public:
    virtual void call(int arg) = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Callback : public AbstractCallback {
public:
    typedef std::mem_fun1_t<void, T, int> CallbackFunc;
private:
    CallbackFunc func;
    T* object;
public:
    Callback(T* _object, const CallbackFunc& _func)
        : object(_object), func(_func) {
    }

    void call(int arg) {
        func(object, arg);
    }
};

struct A {
    void foo(int a) {
        std::cout << "foo " << a << std::endl;
    }
};
struct B {
    void bar(int a) {
        std::cout << "bar " << a << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;

    AbstractCallback* cbs[2] = {
        new Callback<A>(&a, std::mem_fun(&A::foo)),
        new Callback<B>(&b, std::mem_fun(&B::bar)),
    };

    cbs[0]->call(10);
    cbs[1]->call(22);

    delete cbs[0];
    delete cbs[1];

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see pointer-to member functions (of type `A::*` and `B::*`) are wrapped into `std::mem_fun`s and a `Callback` class which is generated for each type (`A` and `B` in this case).

This allows to keep method of any type in vectors, arrays or lists of abstract callbacks.

Comment: None, I did not get the extra arg (thought `std::mem_fun_t` was sufficient).